# Adding three dynamic Char** arrays to one static array. (C)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have three dynamically allocated arrays of `char**` type, how to add them to one static array?
do I need to use a `char***` array?

```
void memory_allocation (char ***array [3],  int* limit)
{ 
int i; //loop control
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    array [i] = (char***) malloc (*limit * sizeof(char*)); 
    if (array [i] == NULL) //must take malloc's failure to allocate memory into account
    printf ("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    exit (1);
}
```

}

Comment: Which language? Please tag the question appropriately. The answers differ between D, Go, C# and Rust.

Comment: can you please show your effort?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: It seem not to work, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: An array of char\*\* is char \*\*array[3], not char \*\*\*array[3]; that would be an array of char\*\*\*.

Comment: NP.  Just remember that the array designation implies another level of pointing, so I think your code could have also been written as mem_allocation(char ***array, int limit), but then you wouldn't have the size, it would just be a raw pointer.

Comment: @Jim it is a "raw pointer" anyway, the `[3]` is alternative syntax for `*` in a function parameter list

Answer (score 2):

An array of char** is char **array[3], not char ***array[3]; that would be an array of char***